# Posting to Sinatra from a mobile app

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

What is the best way to do a Sinatra app if I have a simple post like this:

```
post '/newemail' do
  @email = params[:data]
  @email = Email.new(:email => params[:data])
  @email.save
end
```

But the post is coming from a mobile app where a user is just asked for an email, just an email. And this email should be captured in the Postgres DB through the simple Sinatra API. It is not working like this, I got an Internal Server Error.

Any tips? If it is not possible, how is it possible to do it, I cannot specify a whitelist URL, because the app is in the app store and I don't know where it is coming from.

Thanks!

Comment: `If it is not possible, how is it possible to do it` - good attitude. :)

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: In the console I get Internal Server Error if I am trying to post. In the logs of Heroku I see: WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the Rack protection, you can do this:

```
set :protection, :except => [:http_origin]
```

Alternatively, you can set a whitelist for the protection, like this:

```
set :protection, :origin_whitelist => ['http://address-to-allow.com']
```

You can read more about the protection here: https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection - that's probably a good idea before you go changing anything.

Comment: I did it exactly like you said, but it gives me then at the console the following error: ERROR RuntimeError: you need to set up a session middleware *before* Rack::Protection::RemoteToken

Comment: Also disable the remote_token protections like so: set :protection, :except => [:remote_token, :http_origin]